# composer require: "Could not find package alchemyai/alchemyapi_php"

Tags: symfony, composer-php, alchemyapi

- I follow instruction here to install alchemyapi_php package in symfony2:    https://packagist.org/packages/alchemyai/alchemyapi_php
- I get this error:
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package alchemyai/alchemyapi_php at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
- What possibly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it turns out to be simple, I needed to add "dev-master" as a version like so: `composer require alchemyai/alchemyapi_php "dev-master"`

note: according to symfony2 official document "version-number" is optional http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html

Comment: It is optional as long as there is a version matching the `minimum-stability` settings of your project (in your project it is `stable` according to the error message you got). However, as there is no stable release of the required package, Composer refuses to install any version of it until you either explicitly require a development version of the package (like you did and which is the preferred way) or you lower the `minimum-stability` setting of your application.